# The Gust of Wind spell creates a 10-foot-wide line of wind originating from the caster; how do I center it on a 5-foot grid?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect, battle-map

Characters are on a grid where every square is 5 feet on each side.

The description of the [*gust of wind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gust-of-wind) spell says:

> A line of strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide blasts from you in
> a direction you choose for the spell’s duration.

How do I center a 10-foot-wide line originating from the caster on a grid made out of 5-foot squares?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the basis of your confusion is that a Small or Medium caster would occupy 1 square on the grid, and so literally centering the origin of the line on the caster would cause the AOE to not align to the grid? (That is, say that you're looking at columns A, B, and C; the caster's in column B, and aiming toward the top of the map. If you literally centered the 10-ft-wide line on the caster, the spell's area would cover full squares in column B, but also cover half-squares in both columns A and C. Are you asking if that's the correct/intended method to adjudicate this?)

Comment: Yes this was my question but Thomas already explained to me

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Choose an intersection as the point of origin.

The rules for areas of effect on a grid require that you choose an intersection of squares or hexes as the point of origin. From the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* (pp. 250-251), in the rules for [using miniatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#UsingMiniatures), it says the following about [areas of effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#AreasofEffect):

> Choose an intersection of squares or hexes as the point of origin of an area of effect, then follow its rules as normal. If an area of effect is circular and covers at least half a square, it affects that square.

So you would choose one of the corners of the space you are occupying as the point of origin for *gust of wind*.

*Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* (pp. 86-88) has some additional guidance in the section "[Areas of Effect on a Grid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#AreasofEffectonaGrid)", and even includes examples of how to adjudicate a 10-foot wide line on a grid:

[image: Diagram 2.6: Lines Using Tokens - cardinal directions and diagonals]

Comment: Note that the example diagrams are specifically for the Token Method. The Template Method actually looks different than the examples in this answer, so which variant rule that's being used will affect the answer.